# PowerShell remove lastwrite more than 30 item/folder exclude mulitple subfolders

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a directory where I need to delete all expired for 30 days file and folder but keep anything in the subfolders `C:\TEST\A` and `C:\TEST\B`

Here is the folder structure:

```
|-C:\TEST
 \-C:\TEST\A
 \-C:\TEST\A\A1
  \-C:\TEST\A\A2.txt
   \-C:\TEST\B
 \-C:\TEST\B\B1
  \-C:\TEST\B\B2.txt
   \-C:\TEST\C
 \-C:\TEST\C\C1
  \-C:\TEST\C\C2.txt
     \-C:\TEST\D.doc
     \-C:\TEST\E.txt
```

This is what I have right now, I've try "exclude" and "notlike" but all doesn't work:

```
$before=(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$exfolder=('C:\TEST\A*' , 'C:\TEST\B*') 

Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\TEST' -Recurse |
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $before ) -and ( $_.FullName -notlike $exfolder)} | 
    Remove-Item -force -Recurse

Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\TEST' -Recurse -Exclude $exfolder |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $before } |
    Remove-Item -force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain two `Get-ChildItem` calls, the first to exclude the folders and the second to recursively get files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder -Exclude A,B | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object [...]
```

Comment: Hi James , Finally I try -Exclude 'A*' , 'B*' then it work , thank you for help~

Comment: Ah that must be a difference to PS v5 as that's what I use. Glad I could help though, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).